# Difference between $(\cdot , \cdot)$ and $\left< \cdot , \cdot \right>$?

Tags: differential-geometry, inner-products, mathematical-physics

**The following symbols used in [this paper, page 16](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.5511).**

Let $\Sigma \subset M$ be a hypersurface.

So I have

$$ A(\nabla\varphi,\nabla\psi) =  A_{ij}\nabla^i \varphi \nabla^j \psi \tag{1}$$

where $A_{ij}$ is the second fundamental form of $\Sigma$ and $\varphi \in C^\infty(\Sigma)$ is some real function.

Next I have

$$H \left< \nabla\varphi , \nabla \psi \right> = H\ \nabla^i \varphi \nabla_i \psi \tag{2}$$

where $H = g^{ij}A_{ij}$ is the mean curvature which is a trace of the second fundamental form $A_{ij}$.

**Questions:**

1. If I replace $\psi$ with $\phi$, then I can write (1) as

$$A(\nabla\varphi,\nabla\varphi) = A|\nabla\varphi|^2 \tag{3}$$

and (2) as

$$ H\ \nabla^i \varphi \nabla_i \varphi = H |\nabla\varphi|^2  \tag{4}$$

I am pretty sure that (4) is right, but how about (3) is it right or wrong?

2. What is the difference between brackets $(\cdot , \cdot)$ and $\left< \cdot , \cdot \right>$?

**Additional information:**

$|A|^2 = A^{ij}A_{ij} \tag{5}$

where $A$ is the shape operator of $\Sigma$.

Thank you.

Comment: Symbols aren't used uniquely in mathematics. In some contexts a symbol might mean X and in another context it might mean Y. It is possible that someone might give a likely interpretation of the symbols, but ultimately it should be defined in the text you're using, and you should be the one to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ is the metric on $\Sigma$ and there is no such thing as $(\cdot, \cdot)$.

The second fundamental form is defined as 
$$ A : T_x\Sigma \times T_x\Sigma \to \mathbb R, \ \ \ A(X, Y) = \langle \nabla^M_X Y, v\rangle,$$
here $v$ is the unit normal vector.

Thus there is no such thing as $(\cdot, \cdot)$, and $A|\nabla \varphi|^2$ does not make sense too.

On the other hand, $H \langle \nabla\varphi, \nabla \varphi\rangle$ does make sense: $H$ is the mean curvature, which is just a function. Thus $H \langle \nabla\varphi, \nabla \varphi\rangle$ is the multiplication between $H$ and the metric $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle$.

Comment: thank you so much!